# Spit string and remove rest of string after [n] character

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string `srting=123d*gss6agn`
How i can remove everything after `=` and leave empty
Should i use re or string modules, how can i solve it

Comment: `print("srting=123d*gss6agn".split("=")[0])` ?

Comment: Do you also want the remove the equals sign?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
a="srting=123d*gss6agn"
a.split("=")[0]+"="
```

or this:

```
a="srting=123d*gss6agn"
a[:a.index("=")+1]
```

To open a file:

```
with open("path/to/your/file.txt","r") as f:
    a=f.read() # and then use an option above
```

Comment: and what if the string i what to split is in other folder `.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use regular expressions... though I personally would opt for the other answer.

```
import re 
a = "srting=123d*gss6agn"
result = re.sub(r'=.','=',a)
```

to substitute all text after an equals sign with a single equals sign.

Comment: Correct it: r'=.' must r'=.*'

Answer (score 1):

With partition():

```
    s='srting=123d*gss6agn'
    s,separator,remainder=s.partition("=")
    print(s)
Out:
   'srting'
```

(No exception if '=' is missing.)

Just playing:

```
    import re
    re.sub(r"(?<==).*",lambda m: m[0][::-1],s)
    Out: 'srting=nga6ssg*d321'

(?<==) lookbehind ?<= for'='; so '=' isn't captured for replacing;
sub's 2nd arg can be a function, too, which got the match object, here 'm'.
```